# Add filename of each file as a separator row when merging into a single file Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the current script which combines all the CSV files in a folder into a single CSV file and it works great. I need to add functionality to add the filename of the original csv's as a header row for each data block so I know which section is which.

Can someone assist as this is not by strong point and I am over my head

```
#!/bin/bash
OutFileName="./Data/all/all.csv"          # Fix the output name
i=0                                       # Reset a counter
for filename in ./Data/all/*.csv; do 
if [ "$filename"  != "$OutFileName" ] ;   # Avoid recursion 
then 
if [[ $i -eq 0 ]] ; then 
head -1  $filename >   $OutFileName       # Copy header if it is the first file
fi
tail -n +2  $filename >>  $OutFileName    # Append from the 2nd line each file
i=$(( $i + 1 ))                           # Increase the counter
fi
done
```

I will be automating this and using and run shell script in apple automator.

Thank you got any help.

This is one of the files that are imported and output example
[Example of current input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKwdN.png)
[Once combined I need the filename where the "headers are"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi0zQ.png)

Comment: Hi Alex, please add example input and output to your question.

Comment: I have added some images to give examples and context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to generate something like ...

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
file1.csv
a,b,c
x,y,z
file2.csv
1,2,3
9,9,9
file3.csv
...
```

... then you just have to insert an `echo "$filename" >> "$OutFileName"` in front of the `tail` command. Here is an updated version of your script with some minor improvements.

```
#!/bin/bash
out="./Data/all/all.csv"
i=0
rm -f "$out"
for file in ./Data/all/*.csv; do 
    (( i++ == 0)) && head -1 "$file"
    echo "$file"
    tail -n +2 "$file"
done > "$out"
```

Comment: This doesn't produce valid CSV.

Comment: @tripleee Not a problem if OP wants an invalid CSV file. However *invalid* is a strong word in this context since CSV files are not strictly standardized.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "header line" other than the first line of the CSV file. What you can do is add a new column.

I've switched to Awk because it simplifies the script considerably. Your original would be literally a one-liner.

```
awk -F , 'NR==1 { OFS=FS; $(NF+1) = "Filename" }
    FNR>1{ $(NF+1) = FILENAME }1' all/*.csv >all.csv
```

Not saving the output in the same directory as the inputs removes the pesky corner case handling.